# Is there any commercial product that builds on SSRS for a richer user experience in a Windows application?

Tags: c#, .net, ssrs-2008, windows

I have a Windows application that displays SSRS 2008 reports.

There is a limitation in SSRS where one can not adjust the width of a parameter listbox or easily navigate to an item in the list e.g. to find to a specific client in a list of 500 clients you would have to type in the first letter of the client name and thereafter scroll down to the item. Typing in the next letter in the name would cause the selected item to change to the first item starting with that letter.

There is a hack to fix the first issue regarding the column width which involves [editing a SSRS style sheet](http://blogs.law.harvard.edu/brandonhaynes/2008/09/24/changing-the-size-of-reportviewer-parameter-dropdown-list/) (which I could not get working anyway) but still leaves the issue of navigating to items in the list.

It seems that Microsoft is not interested in attending to these issues as its been this way since the early versions of SSRS.

Due to time constraints developing a custom ReportViewer control will not be possible. Is there any product (of the likes of DevExpress for Windows controls) that can be added on to SSRS to solve these issues?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

One of the best ways is to use the ReportViewer control for presentation of data, but the hosting web page/win form for parameter management.

And the ReportViewer control is in local, not remote mode.

SSRS is great for showing the data but the parameters to feed the filters are crap...